Debezium and Kafka Connect. Track changes of specicfic rows selected by SQL
Is it possible to track changes only on table subset? For example: we have FK column 'some_fk_id' and we want debezium to track changes only for rows according to such query: select * from some_table where some_fk_id not in (select some_fk_id from some_table_2 where some_field <> 'some_value')
I read about transforms.filter, but it does not work with SQL
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/filtering.html

Explain why filtering doesn't work? You'll get all the changes from the database, but you'll only receive a subset within the topic... Otherwise, sounds like you should be using JDBC source connector

Thank you for reply! Filtering does not work with SQL, especially with a query with subselect

I see... You could move that logo into ksqlDB or Kafka Streams? Or your apps logic?

No, unfortunately. The idea was - not to deliver such messages at kafka at all. Ofcourse, we can add some filters during messages processing, but i was wandering - is it possible to filter on debezioum side

There's other kafka connect transforms that can be added to the  Debezium server. It doesn't need to be a Debezium specific feature. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/filter-confluent.html#examples
